# Problem when trying to submit form as a not authorized user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Sorry for the title but I didn't know how to explain it in just one sentence.
I have a view with form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Restaurants"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.NewComment.Body)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Restaurant.Id)
    <button type="submit">Add comment</button>
}
```

And AddComment Action in Restaurants controller:

```
public ActionResult AddComment(RestaurantViewModel model, Comment newComment)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);

    newComment.RestaurantId = model.Restaurant.Id;
    newComment.AuthorId = Guid.Parse(userId);
    newComment.AuthorName = user.UserName;
    newComment.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

    _context.Comments.Add(newComment);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Restaurants", new { id = model.Restaurant.Id});
}
```

And I added authorize filter:

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

When I try to submit a form as a not logged user, it redirects me to the log in page. If I log in on that page, it calls `AddComment` Action but it pass arguments  `Model.Restaurant` and `NewComment.Body` as nulls. How to fix it, so when I log in, it redirects me to the previous page with filled TextBox or just call `AddComment` but pass proper values of arguments.

Comment: If you add a filter requiring that the user be authorized on every action, and the user isn't authorized, what did you think was going to happen? Have you considered instead only requiring authorization on action methods that need authorization?

Comment: I was expecting something like this: I'm not logged in => I click Add comment button => redirected to log in page => I'm logging in => redirected to page with an adding comment form. What Iam currently getting is: I'm not logged in => I click Add comment button => redirected to log in page => I'm logging in => AddComment action is called and passed arguments are nulls. If I click add comment when I'm already logged in everything works, passed arguments are fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this. The reason is, that this is not "the way of doing things". If you have a form with a secured POST action, make the corresponding GET page authenticated-only as well.

Comment: Using `filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());` means that every single Action, regardless of its type, is secured with `[Authorize]`. This can certainly happen if session expired *after* reaching this page

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

And adding the notation `[Authorize]` to your method, like:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AddComment(RestaurantViewModel model, Comment newComment)
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId);

    newComment.RestaurantId = model.Restaurant.Id;
    newComment.AuthorId = Guid.Parse(userId);
    newComment.AuthorName = user.UserName;
    newComment.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

    _context.Comments.Add(newComment);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Restaurants", new { id = model.Restaurant.Id});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest doing this outside of the simplest of cases. You can change your form to use `get` instead of `post`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Restaurants", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.NewComment.Body)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Restaurant.Id)
    <button type="submit">Add comment</button>
}
```

Caveats:

- This only will work if you use the built in auth, or your implementation forwards querystring values.
- Second, the values will be in the URL, so they can be tampered with easily.
- Last, but not least, if `AddComment` has the `HttpPost` attribute, you will have to remove that.